# Style 3 inputs below each other

Tags: html, css

I've got a form, and I've got a "+" button, text input and "-" button, as the below image shows. I've got a problem, because I can't style it to look it like on picture on all browsers.

Expected: [image: expected style]

This is how it looks on my page:

On *Chrome* looks:[image] And on
*Safari*: [image] And on
*Explorer*: [image]

Here is the CSS code:

```css
.qty {
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
input.qtyplus {
  padding-top: 4px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-top: 2px black;
  background: black;
  color: #ff6100;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px
}
input.qtyminus {
  width: 34px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-bottom: 2px black;
  background: black;
  color: #ff6100;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
input[type=text] {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-top: 2px black;
  border-bottom: 2px black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 28px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' readonly />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
```

Comment: What browsers does it not work on? That would help a lot with the question.

Comment: I tried in FireFox, Chrome and Safari. Looks good in all of them, i'm guessing IE?

Comment: I can see an issue in Chrome (the 0 is 1px too small).

Comment: guys, I updated the question and added photos

Comment: @Marcin isn't your `field` attribute invalid? You should use `data-*` attributes for custom attributes.

Comment: In another way, I suggest you to use a `table` and add `input`s in it, and then set the borders of table ;).

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
.qty {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
  border-width: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  width: 34px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input.minus {
  border-color: #ff6100 #ff6100 black;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  color: #ff6100;
}

input.plus {
  border-color: black #ff6100 #ff6100;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-style: none solid solid;
  color: #ff6100;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

input.num {
  border-color: black #ff6100;
  border-style: none solid;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

text => button, class changed

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qty minus' field='quantity' />
<input type='button' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty num' readonly />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qty plus' field='quantity' />
```

Comment: Thank you. It works, but on my page in Chrome there is 1px space, do you know how to fix this? Image: http://s4.postimg.org/8khj2r9mh/chr.png

Comment: Yes I could if I can reproduce this to see the styles applied. I can't see that in my local. My Chrome version is 42. May be some other styles are inherited to your bottom div. Try adding `position:relative; top:-1px;` or try reducing `pading-top`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me in Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rucaj2cr/10/

HTML

```
<input type='button' value='-' class='qty qtyminus' field='quantity' />
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' readonly />
<input type='button' value='+' class='qty qtyplus' field='quantity' />
```

CSS

```
.qty {
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-left: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-right: 2px solid #ff6100;
  background: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

input.qtyplus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-top: 2px black;
  color: #ff6100;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  width: 34px;
}

input.qtyminus {
  border-top: 2px solid #ff6100;
  border-bottom: 2px black;
  color: #ff6100;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  width: 34px;
}

input[type=text] {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-top: 2px black;
  border-bottom: 2px black;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 30px;
}
```